# Selenium cannot find an element

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, partiallinktext

I am trying to get selenium to find an element and click on it.

The element is as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-link">search criteria: on support work 'took place on' (grouped by author), from: 2020-10-01, to: 2020-12-31</button>
```

When clicked, this button opens a form within the same URL that allows me to input an upper and lower time restraint. The goal is to get Selenium to fill in the form and click 'Update'.

I've tried a few different methods ('find_element_by_xpath', '...by_class_name', 'WebDriverWait' etc but selenium doesn't ever recognise the button element. Ive all tried skipping this step and trying to fill in the form directly (since its all under the same URL but no luck.

I'm a total beginner so the solution is probably very basic. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Please check if your button present under iframe or not? If possible share your url ?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('btn.btn-link'))`.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work, I just get this `NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"btn.btn-link"}`

Comment: by the way, I interpreted what you wrote in the following way: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('btn.btn-link')`

Comment: the find_element_by_class_name accepts only one class, so that will not work for you. Maybe is you try to find with the following method?

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class='btn btn-link']")`

Answer (score 0):

If you cant locate it by any chance, and also not by an explicit wait, you might need to use pyautogui to select the position of the button, then move the mouse there and click. If you need to scroll down, to make it visible, make sure you implement a scrolling script

Comment: thanks for this response, the problem for me is that this .exe must be able to run in the background and not interruptt the users work flow by taking over their mouse. is there any more information you would like to see to make the problem clearer?

Comment: You can add the url, maybe it helps, maybe not

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as *search criteria: on support work 'took place on' (grouped by author), from: 2020-10-01, to: 2020-12-31* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("search criteria: on support work").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-link' and starts-with(., 'search criteria: on support work')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "search criteria: on support work"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-link' and starts-with(., 'search criteria: on support work')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element is inside a parent with tag iframe:

if it is then you have to first swtich to that iframe:

find the iframe webelement using xpath and then switch to it, and then do the button click

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='something']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

//do your code
// then switch back to main frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```